# How to deal with error 'Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'struct'.'

Tags: matlab

A matlab program which was previously working for fine for about 6 months has starting giving the error

'Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'struct'.' The line where this appears is

```
sampleData.allDiameters= sampleData.allDiameters* pixelToMicron;
```

When I try methods such as a loop or saving as another variable from one of the structure fields it saves the new variable as a structure, which previously it did not do. Some examples of this:

```
for n=1:length(measurements)
    x=measurements(n); %saves x as 1x1 struct
    measurements(n)=x*pixelToMicron;
end 

%%%

measurements=sampleData.allDiameters; %saves measurements as a 276x1 struct
```

This was triggered after a small loop was added which has since been deleted. This was a while loop and hadn't even been included in the main program. Nothing else was edited. For clarity this is the loop (as far as I got with it)

```
function [sampleData]=sphereCheck(sampleData)
%for each object check how spherical each object is 

%Measurement2: use regionprops to measure and record the x and y position
%of the corner of the smallest box which bounds the object [xpos ypos xwidth       ywidth]
measurements2=regionprops(sampleData.binImage, 'BoundingBox');
sampleData.allDiameters


counter=1
while counter<length(measurements2)
%[~ ~ a b]=measurements2(counter);

end
```

I would like know how I can get the structures multiplying again or how I can access the data from the structure to perform operations on it.

Comment: `regionprops` is going to return a struct. How about you take a step back. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I understand regionprops returns a structure and it wasn't previously a problem, when I was using regionprops to record the diameters of all objects in a binary image. The loop shown is the second time I have used regionprops trying to find the bounding box of all the objects in the binary image. It is not currently called in the main function, I'm showing in case it has triggered something I am not aware of.

Comment: can you show a dataexample for `sampleData.allDiameters` or even better `sampleData`?

Comment: Is this what you mean by show 'sampleData'?                                                      `sampleData = 

       threshold: 0.2800
     pixelCutoff: 3
            name: 'nd101 1k'
           image: [1536x2048 uint8]
        binImage: [1536x2048 logical]
    allDiameters: [1x2672 double]`

Comment: I edited the code in the following way which appears to have fixed the issue with multiplying structure though I am not sure why it worked. Before  the code shown in the original issue the call to `regionprops` saved the results straight to to sampleData.allDiameters. The new line splits it into two steps `measurements = regionprops(sampleData.binImage, 'EquivDiameter');
sampleData.allDiameters = [measurements.EquivDiameter];`. The issue is fixed though if anyone has an idea why this works but saving it straight to sampleData.allDiameters doesn't, I'd be very interested.

Comment: Thank you the help offered  u\Suever and u\Finn